# How to change color of n number of turtles out of total in a specific region?

Tags: netlogo

I am working on an infectious disease model, I've created a world with two regions. The specified number of people get initialized in their specific region.

Now, I need to initially infect the same number of people in each region with the disease using the initially_infected  global variable. e.g 10 people infected in one region and 10 in the other region.
The infection should be indicated by changing color of turtles to red.

I've tried using "n-of" but it is not working correctly as want to restrict the initially infected people in their respective regions.

```
    to setup_agents
  
  create-humans green_population [
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = green and not any? humans-here]
    
    set shape "green person"
    set color yellow
    set size 1
    set green_antibodies 0
  ]
  ask n-of initially_infected humans [set color red]
  
  create-humans blue_population [
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = blue and not any? humans-here] 
    set shape "blue person"
    set color yellow
    set size 1
    set blue_antibodies 0  
  ] 
  
  ask n-of initially_infected humans [set color red]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are asking `humans` in general (by using `ask n-of initially_infected humans [set color red]`), and not based on where they are.

You can tackle this in a variety of pretty much equivalent ways. To do it in the tidies way, you should ask yourself **what is the main programming feature that univocally differentiates these two groups**: their shape? the color of the patche they are on? should they hold a turtles-own variable differentiating them? should they be separate breeds?

Whatever you choose this feature to be, use that feature in the `ask n-of ...` statement.

In the fully-reproducible example below, I just use the turtles' color as the distinguishing element:

```
breed [humans human]

globals [
 green_population
 blue_population
 initially_infected
]

humans-own [
 green_antibodies
 starting_region 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  ask patches [
   ifelse (pxcor > 0)
    [set pcolor green]
    [set pcolor blue]
  ]
  
  set green_population 300
  set blue_population 270
  set initially_infected 10
  
  setup_agents
end

to setup_agents
  create-humans green_population [
   move-to one-of patches with [(pcolor = green) AND (not any? humans-here)]
   set color green + 1
  ]  
  
  create-humans blue_population [
   move-to one-of patches with [(pcolor = blue) AND (not any? humans-here)]
   set color blue + 1
  ]
  
  ask n-of initially_infected humans with [color = green + 1] [
   set color red 
  ]
 
  ask n-of initially_infected humans with [color = blue + 1] [
   set color red 
  ]
end
```

Perhaps a more elegant option would be to create a little procedure that takes the populations' color and the quantity to infect as inputs. Modifying only the relevant part of the code, it would be:

```
to setup_agents
  create-humans green_population [
   move-to one-of patches with [(pcolor = green) AND (not any? humans-here)]
   set color green + 1
  ]
  
  create-humans blue_population [
   move-to one-of patches with [(pcolor = blue) AND (not any? humans-here)]
   set color blue + 1
  ]
  
  infect-humans (green + 1) initially_infected
  infect-humans (blue + 1) initially_infected
end

to infect-humans [hue quantity]
  ask n-of quantity humans with [color = hue] [
   set color red 
  ]
end
```

In my example I used the humans' colors as distinguishing factor, but you can easily adapt this to any other thing you might want to use.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I've managed to resolve the issue now.